# Check a radio button in an Angular unit test

Tags: unit-testing, angular

I have a component in Angular with this HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <label for="tipo" class="column">Tipo: </label>
  <div *ngFor="let tipo of tipos" class="column">
    <input type="radio" name="tipo" [value]="tipo.id" 
      [(ngModel)]="movimiento.tipo" (ngModelChange)="alCambiarTipo()">
    <span class="{{tipo.texto | lowercase}}">{{ tipo.texto }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

It has two radio buttons, and on change it triggers a function in my component. In my test I want to check the second radio button to test that my function is called. I've tried this code but It's not working:

```
it('should call alCambiarTipo on radio button change', () => {
  spyOn(component, 'alCambiarTipo').and.callThrough();
  let options: DebugElement[] = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('input[type="radio"]'));
  let secondOption: HTMLInputElement = options[1].nativeElement;
  secondOption.checked = true;
  expect(component.alCambiarTipo).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I've also tried using `.click()` on the input and it's also not working. What can I do to trigger my function? Thanks.

PS: I've also tried to change the model adding `component.movimiento.tipo = 1;` and calling `fixture.detectChanges()` and it's also not working.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Have you resolved this?

Answer (score 7):

The answer from @maxisam is correct, additionally you could use:

`inputElement.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));`

If you want more compact form :)

Answer (score 6):

Because you use a wrong event. It should be **change** event.

```
  options[1].triggerEventHandler('change', { target: options[1].nativeElement });
```

You don't even need to set check